# Rest api Method call morethan one time

Tags: rest, nopcommerce

I develop REST api plugin method in nopcommerce for getting all product list from product table, but any how my method call two times ! that i want to call only ones.

```
public IList<ProductAllResponse> GetAllProducts(string apiSecretKey, int storeId, int languageId)
    {

      var  _productRepository = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IRepository<Product>>();

        var GetAllProducts = new List<ProductAllResponse>();

        try
        {

            if (!CheckAPIKey(apiSecretKey, storeId))
            {
                GetAllProducts.Add(new ProductAllResponse { Message = _localizationService.GetResource("Plugins.XcellenceIT.RestApi.Message.CheckApi") });
                return GetAllProducts;
            }

            var query = (from p in _productRepository.Table
                         where p.Published && !p.Deleted
                         select new
                         {
                             Id = p.Id,
                             Name = p.Name

                         }).ToList();

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                GetAllProducts.Add(new ProductAllResponse { Id = item.Id, Name = item.Name });
            }

            return GetAllProducts;
        }

        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            _logger.Error(exc.Message);
            GetAllProducts.Add(new ProductAllResponse { Message = exc.Message });
            return GetAllProducts;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is test 
okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here issue is in `ProductAllResponse`, this response class inherited from other class `contextClass`, and this both of class has same property called `Id`.

When I removed `Id` from `ProductAllResponse` and it's now call one time.